# rtabmap_ros tutorial not working : executable not found

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, ros-lunar, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey :-)

**System**: Ubuntu 16.04

**ROS**: Lunar (tried Kinetic before) Desktop Full

**rtabmap version** : 0.13.2

My approach ist to use the rtabmap feature in cooperation with Tango ROS Streamer which is already running fine.

I followed the instructions on this tutorial :

http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/Tango%20ROS%20Streamer

At step 6 it fails at this command

```
rosrun rtabmap_ros pointcloud_to_depthimage cloud:=/tango/point_cloud camera_info:=/tango/camera/color_1/camera_info _fixed_frame_id:=start_of_service _decimation:=8 _fill_holes_size:=5
```

with the error:

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named pointcloud_to_depthimage below /opt/ros/lunar/share/rtabmap_ros
```

I already installed rtabmap via:

```
sudo apt install ros-lunar-rtabmap-ros
```

What could go wrong ? -_-

best regards and many thanks in advance for any help

Mark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280296/rtabmap_ros-tutorial-not-working-:-executable-not-found/) by [Markovicho](https://answers.ros.org/users/33312/markovicho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2018-01-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-01-19**:
Did you get any errors when you installed rtabmap? Have your sourced the setup.bash file for ros?

### **Comment by [Markovicho](https://answers.ros.org/users/33312/markovicho/) on 2018-01-19**:
No errors on the installation...
setup.bash is attached to my ~/.bashrc as well running "rosdep init && rosdep update"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have already seen the same error, but forgot to write an error report.
pointcloud_to_depthimage seems not to be included in the deb package or is not installed.
I've compiled rtabmap from source.

---

Originally posted by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) with karma: 476 on 2018-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markovicho](https://answers.ros.org/users/33312/markovicho/) on 2018-01-22**:
Thanks a lot !!!

This worked:

- Create catkin Workspace :
  http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace
- Follow build instructions on
  :https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros#rtabmap_ros-
- Adding ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash  to ~/.bashrc